# Route SSH to host through interface

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ip, route

Is it possible to route all outgoing requests for SSH (port 22) to `mydynamicdns.afraid.org` via `wlan0` instead of `eth0` when both are connected?

Since my IP is dynamic, I would like to use a name instead of IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could mark all packets matches such policy, and control the route like this,

```
# Set mark for out going packets
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d mydynamicdns.afraid.org -j MARK --set-mark 1

# Route all packets with mark 1 through wlan0
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
ip route add XXX table 1 dev wlan0
```

P.S The rule would not work if DNS resolution fails

Comment: Thanks, I am using Ubuntu, will this work? Is IPTABLES a file that I can hand edit?

Comment: @Jorge it's a set of command

Comment: Thanks, how can I see the rules I have added and/or delete them?

Comment: @Jorge `ip rule; iptables -t mangle -L; ip route`