# How to route "single ip" to different interfaces

Tags: networking, routing

i have a dd-wrt router (ip 192.168.1.1) with the following network interfaces:

- eth0
- ath0
- ppp0 (a pptp vpn client)

i would like to route all traffic from ip 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.20 through ppp0 interfaces.

Is it possible maybe with iptables ?

**EDIT**: i'm using dd-wrt v24sp2 running i think busybox

Comment: you are certainly looking for this ? 
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html, also you should complete your question with your OS and what your have try already

Answer (score 0):

You need policy routing in order to do that i.e. several routing tables and a rule set to determine which table to use for a certain packet.

This is explained in the answer to a similar question:

[Route SSH to host through interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66686/route-ssh-to-host-through-interface/)